# Poco::Net::HTTPSClientSession receiveResponse always truncated abnormally

Tags: linux, rest, https, centos, poco

Encountered a very weird issue.
I have two VMs, running CentOS Linux.
Server side has a REST API (Using none-Poco socket), and one of the API is to response a POST.
On the client side, use POCO library to call the REST.

- If the returned message is long, it will be truncated at 176 k, or 240 k, or 288 k.
- Same code, same environment, running on server side, Good.
- On the client VM, use python to do the REST call, Good.

ONLY failed if I use the same good code, on client VM.

When msg got truncated, the https status code always return 200

On the server side, I logged the response message that I sent every time. Everything looks normal.

I have tried whole bunch of things, like:

- set the socket timeout and receiveResponse timeout to an hour
- wait for 2 seconds after I send the request but before I call the receive
- Set the receive buffer big enough
- Try whole bunch of approach to make sure receive stream is empty, no more data

It just does not work.

Anyone have similar issue? I started pulling my hair.... Please talk to me, anything... before I am bold.